# Using VBA to add a row and fill columns with a text

Tags: excel, vba, addition, conditional-formatting

I need to add a row after any row filled in (even partially) and insert automatically a warning if a cell is "No".
Under the column "Is certified?" if the cell is "No" it is automatically colored and a warning appears next to it.
I tried to add a conditional formatting, but for new rows created with the macro this formatting is maintained even when the cell is "Yes".
Here is what I have so far, it works for adding rows. Here in below the text...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Long
     If Target.Column = 3 Then
        r = Target.Row + 1
        Rows(r).Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Cells(r, 1).Select
     End If
     If Target.Column = 5 Then
        r = Target.Row + 1
        Rows(r).Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Cells(r, 1).Select
     End If
End Sub

Sub InsertFormula(ByVal cell As Range)
     Dim cell As Range
     Sheets("Sheet1").Select
     For Each cell In Range("F12:F29")
          If cell.Value = "No" Then
          Range("I12:I29").Select
          Selection.Formula = "IT CAN T BE USED"
          Selection.Colums.AutoFit
          End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I need to add a row after any row filled in (even partially) and insert automatically a warning if a cell is "No".

It might help to post here an image as reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your Worksheet_Change event lacks checking logic. To ensure that a row is only inserted when a user enters "No" in Column C, I would modify the code as follows, this code ensures that a new row is inserted only when "No" is entered in Column C or Column E.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Long
     If Target.Column = 3 Then
        If Target.Value <> "No" Then Exit Sub
        r = Target.Row + 1
        Rows(r).Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Cells(r, 1).Select
     End If
     If Target.Column = 5 Then
        If Target.Value <> "No" Then Exit Sub
        r = Target.Row + 1
        Rows(r).Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Cells(r, 1).Select
     End If
End Sub
```